# Specflow learning resources

Tags: specflow

I know basic Specflow with .NET. I am looking for learning resources, ideally with code examples in .NET, other than below

http://www.specflow.org/, because the documentation is still lack of easy to read examples.

Comment: I know PluralSight has some courses about SpecFlow. Since I haven't seen them (yet) for myself I can't tell you what the level of the courses are, but knowing PluralSight I'm pretty sure they are more than decent courses to get your knowledge up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples, some of them are a bit dated though:

- Steven Sandersson http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/
- TekPub intro http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVwBz-ZTliw
- SpecFlow getting started http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/
- Writing maintainable test code: http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/04/clean-up-your-stepsuse-page-objects-in.html

I think the [documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/) is pretty good for when you got up and running.

Answer (score -1):

A very good [course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/specflow-2-0-business-readable-automated-tests) by Jason Roberts at Pluralsight.
**"Business Readable Automated Tests with SpecFlow 2.0"**, covers topics like following:

- High Level SpecFlow Overview
- SpecFlow Technical Features Overview
- Understanding the Feature File Format
- Step Definition Code
- Getting Started in Visual Studio
- Step Definition Binding Styles
- Creating the First Scenario
- Running and Debugging Test Scenarios
- Four Ways to Improve Maintainability
- Introducing Parameterized Step Definitions
- Introducing Scenario Outlines
- Creating Common Setup Code with Scenario Backgrounds
- Dynamic Step Table Data
- Passing Data Between Step Definitions
- Using Context Injection
- Restricting Step Execution with Scoped Bindings
- Executing Code Before and After Every Scenario
- and more...

Comment: @Daniel Ruf Answer Improved